# What to use instead of value for string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have commented on the code that what should I put instead of value there as I used in Power

```
private int _power;
public int Power{
    get{
        return _power;
    }
    set{
        _power = value;
    }
}

private string _name;
public int Name{
    get{
        return _name;
    }
    set{
        _name = ?; // what should i put here
    }
}
```

Comment: Value as you are setting it to the supplied value. Check how properties work

Comment: ```public int Name``` -> ```public string Name```. ```_name = value;``` Please have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_properties.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do

```
_name = value;
```

but that will be a problem because your field _name is defined as a string but your have specified your property Name as an int.

Change Name to be a string, then set _name = value;

```
private string _name;
public string Name{
    get{
        return _name;
    }
    set{
        _name = value; 
    }
```

As others have posted, there are different ways to use properties in C# - but there's nothing wrong with the way you are doing it - just your typo where you used int instead of string (I bet you copy/pasted the Power property! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Name{
   get; set;
}
```

This removes the whole private property specification and lets you create properties faster.

Value is a language keyword, you can use it to condition whether the value is changed when you return it from the property.

I advice you to read more about how properties work.